# how do I use an id with jquery :contains()?

Tags: jquery

how do I use an id with :contains() selector?

possibly similar to this?

```
$("$("#foo"):contains('John')")
```

thank you

Comment: bookmark the jQuery API and save yourself some effort  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: No reply... alright. Here's the way it works. Voting is for rating the quality and usefulness of the question, and for judging the prior research effort. This question is entirely localized, has no use to future askers, and clearly shows no attempt at finding the solution. Putting some arbitrary code in a string and asking *"possibly similar to this?"* doesn't count as an actual attempt at finding the answer for one's self. When you up-vote questions like this, you undermine the usefulness of the site, and you negate the efforts of others who actually want to help make the site more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `:contains()` is a selector you have to use it together with the element/id/class you want, like so:

```
$("#foo:contains('John')");
```

**EDIT:**
Unless you want to search the whole document, as pointed by @gdoron, using the selector by itself is fine too

```
$(":contains('John')");
```

Comment: This is incorrect! `$(':contains("John")')` Is a perfectly valid selector!

Comment: Just like `$('['type"text"]')` or `$(':text:')` They are all valid selectors. But they do have slow performance, that's right.

Comment: @gdoron while that is correct, my answer was only in the question's context.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$("#foo:contains('John')");
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do:

```
$("#foo:contains('John')")
```

But I would suggest a different technique, because this will be slow (since browsers don't natively understand `contains`).

```
var foo = $('#foo');
if (foo.text().indexOf('John') > -1) {
    // do whatever here
}
```

This will undoubtedly be considerably faster.

Comment: It's a micro-optimization. boost `id selector` won't change much...

Comment: Actually, an `indexOf()` on the text content of the element is exactly what jQuery does when you use the `:contains()` selector.

Comment: @powerbuoy Yes, except my technique avoids using the Sizzle selector engine to get there. It's quite unnecessary in this case, and much, much slower than a simple ID lookup, which can be done with `getElementById`.

Comment: You are correct, sir. Did a quick test and not using `:contains` is indeed roughly ten times faster. Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/3J69c/

Comment: @powerbuoy. `0.00010` instead of `0.00001` is something that I'm willing to sacrifice to make my code cleaner, easier to write and maintain.

Comment: I agree, I also prefer cleaner code most of the time. But ten times faster is quite a lot.